# Unable to ignore eclipse specific files in gitignore

Tags: gitignore

```
#   modified:   bar/.classpath
#   modified:   bar/.gitignore
#   modified:   bar/.project
#   modified:   bar/build.gradle
#   modified:   foo/.classpath
#   modified:   foo/.gitignore
#   modified:   foo/.project
#   modified:   foo/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   .gitignore
```

The project structure is as follows

```
project/foo
project/bar
project/.gitignore
```

I have added the following in project/.gitignore, but it doesn't seem to ignore eclipse settings files.

```
.classpath
.project
.settings
```

How do I make this work recursively from the root project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove from the index those files, for them to be actually ignored:

```
git rm --cached -- foo/.classpath
git rm --cached -- bar/.classpath

git rm --cached -- foo/.project
git rm --cached -- bar/.project

git rm -r --cached -- foo/.settings
git rm -r --cached -- bar/.settings
```

If those files were not yet added and committed to the git repo before, then a simple `git reset` is enough: it will un-staged all those files, and the `.gitignore` rules will apply immediately, as show by the next `git status`.